# Set a var to today's date

Tags: swift, date, datepicker

I have a datePicker field that should not allow the user to select a date in the future. I figured I would use var maximumDate: NSDate? and then set that equal to a var I have defined already to be isToday (var maximumDate: NSDate? = isToday). The date picker already comes up (but does not return the date when selected). Now I need to limit the date picker to only today or any date in the past. Here is how I have it written. I currently have errors on the first line defining the var isToday and at var maximumDate: NSDate? = isToday. Thank you for your assistance.

```
var isToday = NSDate
var season = traSeason
var sport = traSport
var dispenseTo = ["Personnel", "Physician"]

var activeField = []

var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

@IBOutlet var userLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var teamLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var enterDate: UITextField!

@IBAction func dateTapped(sender: UITextField) {

    //code for what to do when date field is tapped
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    enterDate.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

}

func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    var maximumDate: NSDate? = isToday
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    enterDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add this line to your handleDatePicker method to set your date picker property maximumDate to now (NSDate()) :

```
sender.maximumDate = NSDate()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76060/discussion-on-answer-by-leonardo-savio-dabus-set-a-var-to-todays-date).

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make sense. You're creating a brand new date picker, and then never installing it in your view hierarchy. The date picker you're creating never does anything.

Instead you should create a date picker in Interface Builder and control-drag from that date picker to the top part of your view controller class, just inside the braces. That will cause IB to offer to create an IBOutlet. Then in your viewWillAppear method you'd configure the EXISTING date picker in the outlet to set the max date.

This line also makes no sense:

```
var isToday = NSDate
```

What is it even supposed to do? It looks like the variable will be set to the NSDate **class**.

The name is also confusing. With a variable name that begins with "is", I expect it to be a boolean that's true if some date is today, and false otherwise.

I would suggest using this instead:

```
let today = NSDate()
```

That code creates a constant of type NSDate and stores the current and date and time into it. (The compiler can infer that `today` is an NSDate because that's what the `NSDate()` init function returns.)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. As you can tell from my var isToday blunder, I am very new at this. I am unsure what you mean by "your viewWillAppear method". I do not see that anywhere in my code. Also, when you say "the EXISTING date picker" are you referring to the one I linked to a new IBOutlet or the one I have been making with code that does nothing (which would explain why I can't get it to do anything I ask).

Comment: You should add a viewWillAppear: method if you don't have one (see the Xcode docs for it's signature. And yes, I am talking about the picker that is defined in interface builder and connected to an IBOutlet, not the one you create in code (which does nothing useful)